# ruby http connection pool

Tags: ruby, http, connection-pooling, time-wait

I have to create http connections within a rails app to pull some data from a remote server. I am using Net:HTTP, but the http connections created are not persistent. So I end up having lots of sockets in TIME_WAIT state, as these http connections are closed. Anyone knows a good pooling gem which will keep the connections persistent and reuse them?

Comment: Don't open connection on action level, use `initializers` for that so you will have one connection per server process.

Comment: I need multiple connections, so I have to do pooling myself or use a library. Don't want to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: Just found persistent_http. http://rubydoc.info/gems/persistent_http/PersistentHTTP

Answer (score 3):

Use https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool, it's actively maintained.